# Scraping YouTube comments

Tags: r, youtube, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape several comments on YouTube but my id doesn't work and I don't know if i have to use the API or the client id/secret:

```
>id <- "XXX" 
>api <- "xxx" 

>client <-"xxx" 
>secret <- "xxx"

yt_oauth(client, secret) 
yt.oauth(client, secret) 
yt.ouath(client,secret, token = ' ') 
yt_oauth(user, api, token = '') 
# A<- yt_oauth(user,api)

install.packages("devtools")
library (devtools)
devtools::install_github("soodoku/tuber", build_vignettes = TRUE)

#quick overview of some important functions in tuber, see the vignette:
vignette("tuber-ex", package="tuber")

#Get All the Comments Including Replies
get_all_comments(video_id = "a-UQz7fqR3w")
```

---

```
yt.oauth(client, secret) 
Error in yt.oauth(client, secret) : not found the function "yt.oauth"

yt_oauth(user, api, token = '') 
Waiting for authentication in browser...Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
But it doesn't recognize my credentials
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Possible bounty is warranted here. TBD later.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is interesting for you, but I have been able to get the comments of a Youtube video with the following code :

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

port <- as.integer(4444)
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()

url <- 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WzPPRUTQZ4'
remDr$navigate(url)

# Scroll down the page to load all the comments
for(i in 1 : 200)
{
  print(i)
  java_Script <- paste0("scroll(0,", i * 500, ")")
  remDr$executeScript(java_Script)
}

web_Obj_Comments <- remDr$findElements("xpath", '//*[@id="content"]')

list_Comments <- list()
nb_Comments <- length(web_Obj_Comments) - 2

for(i in 1 : nb_Comments)
{
  print(i)
  list_Comments[[i]] <- web_Obj_Comments[[i + 1]]$getElementText()[[1]]
}

vector_Comments <- unlist(list_Comments)
vector_Comments <- vector_Comments[vector_Comments != ""]
```